# Adding .Renvrion to github repo hiding from public

Tags: r, git, github, renviron

If it is a duplicate I am sorry, however I've read lots of threads and
none of them worked and 
only a few of them were related to R.

I want to automate an R script using `github actions`. So doing that
I need to pass some keys, tokens and etc.

However I want to hide them from public while my repo is still public.
What I have done so far is:

`git add -A`(.gitignore does not include .Renviron)

`git commit -m 'message'`

`git push`

(Now this works, but my .Renviron still viewable)

`git add .gitignore`(add .Renviron in .gitignore, while .Renviron is in github repo)

`git commit -m 'message'`

`git push`

(Now this works, but .Renviron is still visible publicly)

Then

`git rm .Renviron`

`git commit -m 'message'`

`git push`

 (This time as you can imagine required environment objects cant be found.)

Any help appreciated. I feel somehow near to the solution but I do something wrong or 
miss
something

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#secrets

Comment: Thank you for sharing.
I took a look, but still do not understand as I am not developer. Because what they document seems to me in a bit difficult language.

Comment: Don't worry, I can write up an answer later today.

Comment: Would appreciate. However what you shared is something githubs's secret rather than hiding your project language env file in .gitignore. However , I look forward to.